# displaying quiz through php and html

Tags: php, html, session

I trying to display a quiz from a list of quizzes depending on the current topic the user has clicked (topics are called sessions). Sessions have exercises and on every exercise I want the option to go to the specific session quiz (A session has 5 exercises and 1 quiz). When the `quiz` button is clicked, I'm trying to display the quiz title and author using the current `$session_id` and linking that to the `session_id` from the `quiz_list` table in the database.

Nothing is displaying and I'm getting errors like:

> Notice: Undefined index: session_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\quiz.php on line 8
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\quiz.php on line 13

exercise.php:

```
<?php 
    //build up array as iterate through while loop
   $sessions_quiz_array = array();
   $get_quiz = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `quiz_list` WHERE `session_id` = $session_id");

   //fetches result row as an associative array
   while ($row_quizes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_quiz)) {
   $sessions_quiz_array[] = $row_quizes;

   }

   //sessions_quiz_array is the associative array being looped 
   foreach ($sessions_quiz_array as $key => $value) {
      $quiz_id = $value['id'];
      $quiz_title = $value['quiz_title'];
      $quiz_author = $value['quiz_author'];
      ?>

    <a id='button' href="quiz.php?id=<?php echo $quiz_id; ?>"> Quiz</a>

    
            <?php  } ?>
```

quiz.php

```
   <?php 
   session_start(); 
   include("includes/database.php");
   ?>
    <?php 
        //gets current
        $session_id = $_GET['session_id'];
    
    $get_quiz = "SELECT * FROM `quiz_list` WHERE `session_id` = $session_id";
    
        $run_quiz = mysqli_query($con, $get_quiz);
        $quiz_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_quiz);
    
     ?>
      <hr>
      <div>
      
        <h1><?php echo $quiz_info["id"]; ?> </h1>
        <br>
        <p><?php echo $quiz_info["quiz_title"]; ?></p>
        <br>
        <p><strong><?php echo $quiz_info["quiz_author"]; ?></strong></p>
        
        
      </div>
      <hr>

      <a href="interactive_training.php" class="button previous">&laquo; Back to Training</a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @FuzzyTree thanks for pointing that out! Fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you file `exercise.php` your GET request is `ID` not `session_id` near `quiz.php?id=`

You need to make following change in your `quiz.php` file.

Change from

```
$session_id = $_GET['session_id'];
```

To

```
$session_id = $_GET['id'];
```

Addiotionally you can add check before executing whole page like

```
if(!isset($session_id))
{
    exit('Session ID is missing');
}
```

Comment: Added the validation and changed the quiz button url to: <a id='button' href="quiz.php?session_id=<?php echo $_GET['session_id']; ?>&&id=<?php echo $quiz_id; ?>"> Quiz</a> And it worked, Thanks!

Comment: @Davidaj I'm glad it works for you. There is double `&&` in your link near `?>&&id=<?php e`

Answer (score 1):

Your quiz.php becomes:-

> replace this

```
 $session_id = $_GET['session_id'];
```

with

```
 $session_id = $_GET['id'];
```